# Symfony2: How to get the latest reply to a post using QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, query-builder

I known that in sql statement the latest reply can be get by adding "order by created DESC limit 0,1"

But how can i get it using QueryBuilder?
I have refered to the document of QueryBuilder . There is no limit() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use ->setMaxResults(1) to say "limit" with doctrine

And the doc': http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/query-builder.html#limiting-the-result ^^

But in this case you should use ->getSingleResult() instide of ->getResult(), without using limit. (It's more appropriated !)

Comment: But getSingleResult() will  throws EntityNotFoundException if there is no result. Weather it can return null?

Comment: In fact you always have to do a try test with doctrine2 ^^ Like this:
    try {
        return $q->getResult();
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }

Comment: You can use getOneOrNullResult() to achieve the same effect http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats